# What is the fastest way to update WPF UI from non UI thread with large volume of messages?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, optimization, c#-4.0

What i have now is a real-time API get bunch of messages from network and feed into pubsub manager class. there might be up to 1000 msg/sec or more at times. there are 2 different threads each connected to its own pubsub. subscribers are WPF windows. manager keeps list of windows and their DispatcherSynchornisationContext.

A thread calls the manager through interface method.

Manager publishes through Post:

```
        foreach (var sub in Subscribers[subName])
        {
            sub.Context.Post(sub.WpfWindow.MyDelegate, data);
        }
```

can this be optimised.

*P.S. Please dont ask why do I think it is slow and all.. I dont have limits. Any solution is infinitely slow. I have to do my best to make it as fast as **possible**. I am asking for help to assess - can it be done faster? Thank you.*

**EDIT: found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument with a queue stays. WHat I do is put stuff into the queue, the queue triggers a task that then invokes into the messaging thread and pulls X items of data (1000, or how many there are). The one thing that killed me was permanent single item invokation (which is slow), but doing it batchy works nicely. I can keep up wiitz nearly zero cpu load on a very busy ES data feed in crazy times for time and sales.

I have a special set of componetns for that that I will open source one of the next week and there is an ActionQueue (taking a delegate to call when items need processing). This is now a Task (was a queued thread work item before). I took time to process up 1000 messages per invocation - but if you do a price grid you may need more.

Note: use WPF hints to enable gpu caching of rendered bitmaps.

In addition:

- Run every window on it's own thread / message pump
- HEAVILY use async queues. The publisher should never block, every window has it's own target queue that is async.

You want processing as decoupled as possible. Brutally decoupled.

Comment: you are right in the money :) i do DOM and test it on ES. the threads are decoupled. i am trying to get stats on how to push it to the UI faster than BeginInvoke on each. BTW most messages are quotes not T&S... I will think about batching. but single item works not bad.... would like to learn about GPU caching. do you have links for that? cheers

Comment: Ok, the batching is something that happens automatically for me. Basicalyl he task dcoems, invokes to the UI thread then works off all items waiting (maximum 1000). If it is finished, it returns. hiThis is better than single item invoke. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/04/12/what-s-new-for-performance-in-wpf-in-net-4.aspx has the information for cached composition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion for you:

I would use a `ConcurrentQueue` (comes with the namespace `System.Collections.Concurrent;`) The background workers feed their messages in that queue. The UI Thread takes a timer and draws (let's say every 500 msec) a bunch of messages out of that queue and shows them to the user. Another possible way is, that the UI thread only will do that on demand of the user. The ConcurrentQueue is designed to be used from different thread and concurrently (as the name says ;-) )

Comment: no the question is how to make fast cross-thread call really.. btw - 500ms is very long time in my system.... p.s. i dont have problems with concurrency anyway.

Comment: @Bobb: 500 msec was just a value. I would try to avoid cross thread calling. That is expensive! I would prefer a seperation of "producing messages" and "showing messages". That is overall faster. You can look every 10 msec for new messages, but then UI thread will not correspond to the user, I think.

Comment: @Bobb: Great. I'm interested in the results.